# How to broadcast or vectorize a linear interpolation of a 2D array that uses scipy.ndimage map_coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, ndimage

I have recently hit a roadblock when it comes to performance. I know how to manually loop and do the interpolation from the origin cell to all the other cells by brute-forcing/looping each row and column in 2d array.

however when I process a 2D array of a shape say (3000, 3000), the linear spacing and the interpolation come to a standstill and severely hurt performance.

I am looking for a way I can optimize this loop, I am aware of vectorization and broadcasting just not sure how I can apply it in this situation.

I will explain it with code and figures

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
m = np.array([
    [10,10,10,10,10,10],
    [9,9,9,10,9,9],
    [9,8,9,10,8,9],
    [9,7,8,0,8,9],
    [8,7,7,8,8,9],
    [5,6,7,7,6,7]])

origin_row = 3
origin_col = 3
m_max = np.zeros(m.shape)
m_dist = np.zeros(m.shape)

rows, cols = m.shape
for col in range(cols):
    for row in range(rows):
        # Get spacing linear interpolation
        x_plot = np.linspace(col, origin_col, 5)
        y_plot = np.linspace(row, origin_row, 5)

        # grab the interpolated line
        interpolated_line = map_coordinates(m,
                                      np.vstack((y_plot,
                                                 x_plot)),
                                      order=1, mode='nearest')
        m_max[row][col] = max(interpolated_line)
        m_dist[row][col] = np.argmax(interpolated_line)

print(m)
print(m_max)
print(m_dist)
```

As you can see this is very brute force, and I have managed to broadcast all the code around this part but stuck on this part.
here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve, I will go through the first iteration

1.) the input array

[image: input array]

2.) the first loop from 0,0 to origin (3,3)

[image: first cell to origin]

3.) this will return [10  9  9  8  0] and the max will be 10 and the index will be 0

5.) here is the output for the sample array I used

[image: sample output of m]

**Here is an update of the performance based on the accepted answer.**

[image: times]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up the code, you could first create the `x_plot` and `y_plot` outside of the loops instead of creating them several times each one:

```
#this would be outside of the loops
num = 5
lin_col = np.array([np.linspace(i, origin_col, num) for i in range(cols)])
lin_row = np.array([np.linspace(i, origin_row, num) for i in range(rows)])
```

then you could access them in each loop by `x_plot = lin_col[col]` and `y_plot = lin_row[row]`

Second, you can avoid both loops by using `map_coordinates` on more than just one `v_stack` for each couple (`row`, `col`). To do so, you can create all the combinaisons of `x_plot` and `y_plot` by using [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) and [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html?highlight=ravel) such as:

```
arr_vs = np.vstack(( np.tile( lin_row, cols).ravel(),
                     np.tile( lin_col.ravel(), rows)))
```

Note that `ravel` is not used at the same place each time to get all the combinaisons. Now you can use `map_coordinates` with this `arr_vs` and `reshape` the result with the number of `rows`, `cols` and `num` to get each `interpolated_line` in the last axis of a 3D-array:

```
arr_map = map_coordinates(m, arr_vs, order=1, mode='nearest').reshape(rows,cols,num)
```

Finally, you can use `np.max` and `np.argmax` on the last axis of `arr_map` to get the results `m_max` and `m_dist`. So all the code would be:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates
m = np.array([
    [10,10,10,10,10,10],
    [9,9,9,10,9,9],
    [9,8,9,10,8,9],
    [9,7,8,0,8,9],
    [8,7,7,8,8,9],
    [5,6,7,7,6,7]])

origin_row = 3
origin_col = 3
rows, cols = m.shape

num = 5
lin_col = np.array([np.linspace(i, origin_col, num) for i in range(cols)])
lin_row = np.array([np.linspace(i, origin_row, num) for i in range(rows)])

arr_vs = np.vstack(( np.tile( lin_row, cols).ravel(),
                     np.tile( lin_col.ravel(), rows)))

arr_map = map_coordinates(m, arr_vs, order=1, mode='nearest').reshape(rows,cols,num)
m_max = np.max( arr_map, axis=-1)
m_dist = np.argmax( arr_map, axis=-1)

print (m_max)
print (m_dist)
```

and you get like expected:

```
#m_max
array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 9,  9, 10, 10,  9,  9],
       [ 9,  9,  9, 10,  8,  9],
       [ 9,  8,  8,  0,  8,  9],
       [ 8,  8,  7,  8,  8,  9],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8]])
#m_dist
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]])
```

EDIT: `lin_col` and `lin_row` are related, so you can do faster:

```
if cols >= rows:
    arr = np.arange(cols)[:,None]
    lin_col = arr + (origin_col-arr)/(num-1.)*np.arange(num)
    lin_row = lin_col[:rows] + np.linspace(0, origin_row - origin_col, num)[None,:]
else:
    arr = np.arange(rows)[:,None]
    lin_row = arr + (origin_row-arr)/(num-1.)*np.arange(num)
    lin_col = lin_row[:cols] + np.linspace(0, origin_col - origin_row, num)[None,:]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is quite fast actually. to generate the lin_col and lin_row is about 20 seconds for an array of shape 3000, 3000. which is really good.
total time to run this for an array of shape 3000, 3000 was 140 seconds. consuming about 17K MB of ram.

Comment: @dfresh22 actually, lin_row and lin_col are related, it is possible to create one from the other by a simple addition and slicing, wIth a if statement to find if cols >= rows. also you don't need to use `np.linspace`, there is a faster waysee my EDIT

Comment: yea good call on the lin row and lin col. sorry, I did not respond sooner, I got caught up with the holiday season. I see what you did with the lin_col, that is pretty cool. I can understand why that is much faster. Thank you so much. I will mark as right.

Comment: I tested it, wow that edit is exponentially faster for lin row and cols.
I updated the question to include the timing/performance I got from your answer, thanks again.

Comment: @dfresh22 When I answered first, I was more focused on the `map_coordinates` and how to not mistaken when using `reshape`, but when you said that `lin_col/row` was 20s, even if it was for 3000 elements, it seems really long... Anyway, thanks for the timing/memory used, I would have never guessed that this kind of image processing takes so much memory !!

Comment: it is crazy how much it uses. now I am working on trying to multiply m * 5 + arr_map haha fun times

Comment: yea I found the multiplication to be pretty easy actually. m[:, :, np.newaxis] + arr_map

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sort-of-vectorized approach. It is not very optimized and there may be one or two index-off-by-one errors, but it may give you ideas.

Two examples a monochrome 384x512 test pattern and a "real" 3-channel 768x1024 image. Both are uint8.
This takes half a minute on my machine.

For larger images one would require more RAM than I have (8GB). Or one would have to break it down into smaller chunks.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And the code

```
import numpy as np

def rays(img, ctr):
    M, N, *d = img.shape
    aidx = 2*(slice(None),) + (img.ndim-2)*(None,)
    m, n = ctr
    out = np.empty_like(img)
    offsI = np.empty(img.shape, np.uint16)
    offsJ = np.empty(img.shape, np.uint16)
    img4, out4, I4, J4 = ((x[m:, n:], x[m:, n::-1], x[m::-1, n:], x[m::-1, n::-1]) for x in (img, out, offsI, offsJ))
    for i, o, y, x in zip(img4, out4, I4, J4):
        for _ in range(2):
            M, N, *d = i.shape
            widths = np.arange(1, M+1, dtype=np.uint16).clip(None, N)
            I = np.arange(M, dtype=np.uint16).repeat(widths)
            J = np.ones_like(I)
            J[0] = 0
            J[widths[:-1].cumsum()] -= widths[:-1]
            J = J.cumsum(dtype=np.uint16)
            ii = np.arange(1, 2*M-1, dtype=np.uint16) // 2
            II = ii.clip(None, I[:, None])
            jj = np.arange(2*M-2, dtype=np.uint32) // 2 * 2 + 1
            jj[0] = 0
            JJ = ((1 + jj) * J[:, None] // (2*(I+1))[:, None]).astype(np.uint16).clip(None, J[:, None])
            idx = i[II, JJ].argmax(axis=1)
            II, JJ = (np.take_along_axis(ZZ[aidx] , idx[:, None], 1)[:, 0] for ZZ in (II, JJ))
            y[I, J], x[I, J] = II, JJ
            SH = II, JJ, *np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, img.shape))][2:]
            o[I, J] = i[SH]
            i, o = i.swapaxes(0, 1), o.swapaxes(0, 1)
            y, x = x.swapaxes(0, 1), y.swapaxes(0, 1)
    return out, offsI, offsJ

from scipy.misc import face

f = face()
fr, *fidx = rays(f, (200, 400))
s = np.uint8((np.arange(384)[:, None] % 41 < 2)&(np.arange(512) % 41 < 2))
s = 255*s + 128*s[::-1, ::-1] + 64*s[::-1] + 32*s[:, ::-1]
sr, *sidx = rays(s, (200, 400))

import Image
Image.fromarray(f).show()
Image.fromarray(fr).show()
Image.fromarray(s).show()
Image.fromarray(sr).show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am going to give this a shot tomorrow, I can check tomorrow, but how many pixels in the raccoon image?

Comment: The full racoon is 768x1024x3 I think. This is about the largest I can do and takes 30 seconds. The limiting resource is memory (I have 8GB).

Comment: The expensive thing are the rays. In your example you have them fixed at 5 pixels, but to properly sample a larger image you need many more.